# Direct url for portal.office.com using Custom Branding

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is it possible to acces the Office 365 **portal** using a direct Custom Branding url ?

The only documented url for hitting the custom branding page are the Following:

- https://outlook.com/contoso.com
- https://passwordreset.microsoftonline.com/?whr=contoso.com
- https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/proofup.aspx?whr=contoso.com

However similar url for the portal does not work:

- http://portal.office.com/?whr=contoso.com

and the Following looks fine untill I click LogOut:

- https://login.microsoftonline.com/?whr=contoso.com&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fportal.office.com

Thanks in advance

N